# CakePHP pagination don't sort with custom query

Tags: sorting, cakephp, pagination

In my CakePHP project I need to get data with custom query and paginate this. I succeed with a custom pagination function like this:

```
public function paginate($conditions, $fields, $order, $limit, $page = 1, $recursive = null, $extra = array()) {

    $recursive = -1;

    $sql = "
        SELECT Post.*, ....
        FROM
            (SELECT  ....) //this is my problem
        AS Post1 
        LEFT JOIN ...
        LEFT JOIN ...
        LEFT JOIN 
        LEFT JOIN 
        LEFT JOIN
        GROUP BY Post1.id 
        ORDER BY ...
        LIMIT " . (($page - 1) * $limit) . ', ' . $limit;
    $results = $this->query($sql);
    return $results;
}
```

The result that I want is correct, the Paginator divides correctly the row  according to the limit value for one page.
But the sort function:

```
echo $this->Paginator->sort('id', 'ID'); //don't works
```

if I don't use a custom paginator function, this works fine but I can't retrieve my specific data like custom query.

It's possible with this settings example:

```
$this->paginate = array(
 'limit' => 10,
 'fields' => array('Post.id', 'Post.title', 'Post.created'),
 'conditions' => array('Post.title LIKE' => '%search_keyword%'),
 'order' => array('Post.title' => 'asc', 'Post.id' => 'asc')
 );
```

run a custom query like this:

```
SELECT Post.*, ....
            FROM
                (SELECT  ../*complex query*/...) // <--this is my problem!!
            AS Post1 
            LEFT JOIN ...
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to use the passed arguments `$fields` and `$order` in your custom query if you want to use them the way you describe it. It's logical that it won't sort if you don't use the `$order` within your query.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it with passing custom $order